# Modify the parameter of a function only once

Tags: haskell

I started with Haskell a few days ago. 
I have the following piece of code (recursive function):

```
totaltime t [x] = 0
totaltime t route = tbd + totaltime (t+tbd) (tail(route))
    where tbd = timebetweendepartures (fst(route!!0)) (fst(route!!1)) t (snd(route!!1))
```

"route" is a list of tuples, e.g: [(3,1), (1,2), (5,2), (2,1)]

What I'm trying to do, is to add (0,0) to the route before the function even starts doing what it's supposed to do.

So if the parameter route is passed as [(3,1), (1,2), (5,2), (2,1)] then the function should receive it as [(0,0), (3,1), (1,2), (5,2), (2,1)]

I could just do `totaltime t ((0,0):route)`, but since the function is recursive this won't work as intended.

Ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: you can scope the function `totaltime` into a `where` clause, and expose another function that prepends the list with `(0,0)`:

```
totaltime t l = tt t ((0,0):l)
where tt t [x] = 0
      tt t route = tbd + tt (t+tbd) (tail(route))
          where tbd = timebetweendepartures (fst(route!!0)) (fst(route!!1)) t (snd(route!!1))
```

But that being said, the code is quite inelegant and probably unsafe:

- you do not define a case for an empty list;
- the case that is used for the empty list is the second clause, where you call `!!0` and `!!1` which are functions that are not *total*.

Furthermore it is not very elegant you call `fst` and `snd`. We can introduce patterns in the head of the clause that ususally make it more elegant and easier to understand. We can thus rewrite our `tt` function to:

```
tt t [] = ... # create a case for the empty list
tt t [x] = 0
tt t ((x0,_):xys@((x1,y1):_)) = tbd + tt (t+tbd) xys
    where tbd = timebetweendepartures x0 x1 t y1
```

so now we can use it like:

```
totaltime t l = tt t ((0,0):l)
    where tt t [] = ... # create a case for the empty list
          tt t [x] = 0
          tt t ((x0,_):xys@((x1,y1):_)) = tbd + tt (t+tbd) xys
              where tbd = timebetweendepartures x0 x1 t y1
```

Of course in this case, it would be impossible to ever handle the empty list, since `totaltime` prepends `(0,0)` we have guarantees that the initial call is a call with at least one element, and we perform recursion on the direct tail, so that means that the list decreases with one at a time.

We still can however improve the function by using three arugments: the `t` variable; the head of the list, the tail of the list, and rewrite it to:

```
totaltime t = tt t (0,0)
    where tt _ _ [] = 0
          tt t (x0,_) (xyh@(x1,y1):xyt) = tbd + tt (t+tbd) xyh xyt
              where tbd = timebetweendepartures x0 x1 t y1
```

Now the code is syntactically total, and furthermore it can boost efficiency (since we avoid unpacking some parts of the list twice.

We can still improve the code. Notice that we only take the *first* element of the head of the list (we do not use an `y0` variable). So we can omit packing and unpackand and rewrite it to:

```
totaltime t = tt t 0
    where tt _ _ [] = 0
          tt t x0 ((x1,y1):xyt) = tbd + tt (t+tbd) x1 xyt
              where tbd = timebetweendepartures x0 x1 t y1
```

Now we save on unpacking tuples and it is more clear what we do.

Comment: Do you really need the empty list case, though? Seems it starts with at least one element (that dummy we added) and shrinks by exactly one each iteration. Of course, maybe we can add the empty case to then avoid the wrapper altogether.

Comment: @Thilo: personally I more fan of constructing functions that handle all possible patterns (one can throw an `error "Should not occur"`). But simply leave it that way, is imho not a good idea.

Comment: I'd be tempted to go further. In the last attempt, there's no real way to define the empty case, and we don't even need that. I'd pass the first list element to `tt` as another argument. E.g. `tt t (0,0) l` where `tt t x [] = 0 ; tt t (x0,_) xys@(...)=...`. (Still, the direction is the right one, so +1)

Comment: Another option is to use a `NonEmpty`. This seems clearer than an extra argument, and will likely be optimized away.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the function into an "entry-point" function that does the pre-processing of the externally received parameters:

```
 totaltime t route =
   totaltime' t ((0,0):route)
   where
      totaltime' t [x] = 0
      totaltime' t route = .....
```